# POST UIImage with multiple fields

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, post, nsmutableurlrequest

Found plenty of code examples of how to POST a UIImage to a server that I can successfully do, having a little trouble trying to include fields in the request, in addition to the UIImage itself.

As an example, i'd like to POST the following..

```
UIImage *image = imageView.image;

NSString *userString @"user_id=5";
NSString *typeString @"type=7";
```

Thanks for your help. Like I said, sending a UIImage is fine, adding fields to the request is what i'm having trouble with.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022108/sending-an-nsmutable-array-to-a-php-script-in-ios/9022141#9022141

Comment: Yes i've spent the last 30 minutes trying to figure it out, i'm more than comfortable in obj-c but my knowledge is limited when it comes to HTTP and POST requests in general. I'm not one of those people who comes here expecting to have an app written for them if that's what you are implying buddy.

Comment: Thanks for the link SAKrisT, however that just describes how to send values on their own, sending this along with NSData has proved a little tricky.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do something like:

NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f);

The number in that call is the image compression quality (1.0 is no compression). Then you will need to get the string representation of this data. Then escape your string for inclusion in a URL. And finally base64 encode it. Then set the httpBody of your request to be the string, along with your other parameters.

If you need any further help with how to do this, let me know :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I can send the UIImage fine (it's worth noting).. I just can't seem to send fields with it. I've had a look here but the code example at the bottom doesn't seem to work.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615836/uiimage-uploading-using-nsmutable-request

Comment: As long as your string is in the form "var1=value1&var2=value2&image=escapedEncodedImageString" then your should be able to do it all fine.

Comment: use [request setHttpBody:bodyString]; rather than setData:.